# How we can call the function only when we go back to the previous screen from the next screen in react native?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I need to call the api only when we back from the next screen to previous screen and it should not be called on the first time when we go to the screen in react native.

Comment: I can answer you. BUt, I want to see more of your code , How you had did so far

Comment: i just want to call a function when i go back to the previous screen from the next screen, but this function should not be called on the first time. I have no specific code for this

Answer (score 0):

The approach I use in such situations is to pass a route param that would trigger that particular api on the parent screen. I am assuming you are using React Native Navigation V6. In that case the child would have code like this:

```js
navigation.navigate('parentScreenName', {callAPI: true})
```

and in your parent element the code will look like:

```js
const parentElement = ({navigation, route} : parentElementProps) => {
const callAPI = route.params?.callAPI;
if(callAPI){
// do api call 
}
//rest of your code
}
```

So when you land on this screen from anywhere else then the callAPI is undefined and so the api call wont trigger but when you navigate back from the child screen then the api is triggered because callAPI is true and you get your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass params from your 2nd screen like ,

```js
//Back Button Functionality
const okHandle = (FromScreen ) => {
    navigation.navigate("Settings", { FromScreen });
  };
  
 
 //UI for your back button
  <Button okHandle={() => okHandle("FromSecondScreen")} />
```

And in the first screen you can do it like this using useEffect hook,

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (FromScreen === "FromPreviousScreen") {
     //Whatever function you can call here.
      };
    }
  }, [FromScreen]);
```

This useEffect will be called

Answer (score 0):

Like i have screen A and screen B, If i wanted to call function from screen B at the time of call back press button which i have created on screen A.
Just check below exampl:

```
const A = () => {

//Whenever this function will call api will hit and updated response will update on this screen.
const reloadScreen = () =>{

}

const onPressGoToScreenB = () => {

navigate('B', {reloadScreen: reloadScreen})

  }

return(<Button onPress={() => onPressGoToScreenB} />)
}
```

Now Check screen B

const B = () => {

```
const onBackPress = () => {
route?.params?.reloadScreen()
back()
  }

return(<Button onPress={() => onBackPress} />)
}
```